# My facebook app loads two times

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have wrote facebook app by using **facebook php-sdk**. I want to integrate it to fun page. So when user will go  to my app first of all he must click to like button then use app. I use the `var_dump()` function to see what happens with `$like_status` variable during apps loading.At first `$like_status = false`, because user didn't click to like button, but when user click to like button page reloads and the `$like_status` variable becomes `NULL` and page loads the same picture without page like tab. I think that my page reloads two times and `$like_status` variable becomes `NULL`. Here is my application link https://www.facebook.com/pages/Tasty-Applications/456339624439381?id=456339624439381&sk=app_570550412956864. I hope that my question clear and readable. Please I need help. Here is my code.

```
 <?php
 require_once('facebook.php');
 $app_id = 'app_id';
 $my_url = "https://apps.facebook.com/losts_app/";
 $config = array(
 'appId' => 'app_id',
 'secret' => 'app_secret',
 'fileUpload'  => true,
 'cookie' => true,
 );
 $facebook = new Facebook($config);
 $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();


$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];



$code = $_GET["code"];

if($like_status)
 {


 session_start();
 $code = $_GET["code"];

 if(empty($code))
 {     
   $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
   . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
   . $_SESSION['state']."&scope=read_stream, user_photos, publish_stream";

   echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
  }
 else {
  //here is my application main content...
  }
}
else
{

   echo('<image src="Like.jpg" />');
   // Here is content that must encourage user to like the page
}
?>
```